# Geany Mini-script scripting documentation?

Tags: geany

I'd like to write a couple of scripts to extend Geany, but I can't find the documentation for it. I've looked at the half-dozen scripts you can download, but none of them do what I want, which is to do multiple finds and replaces quickly. Where can I find that information? (Or do I misunderstand the purpose of Mini-Script plug-in?)

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/geany/geany-plugins/blob/master/geanyminiscript/doc/gms_help.pdf? From a quick look, it seems this plugin lets you specify scripts (shell, sed, perl, etc.), and I guess it just pipes the text (selection or whole document) to that script and replaces it with the output. So for "multiple finds" your script will need to do the finding, so ... just use a script directly?